# Access buckets across projects in gcp using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have two projects on my gcp account and both of them have buckets.
On one of the projects, I have a dataproc cluster on which I am running hive.
From this hive, I want to access the buckets of the other project. 
I have tried giving ACL permissions to my bucket, but I still get the error when I execute a create table command from hive, saying:

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.io.IOException Error accessing: bucket: *bucketname*, object: *folder/filename*.

How can I access my bucket using hive ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation? It may have what you're looking for: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#other_sparkhadoop_clusters

Comment: Does the Dataproc service account name@[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com have the right permissions on that bucket?

Comment: @MonicaPC I had to give accurate permissions in the bucket to my service account.

Comment: @Sneha K I'm glad it worked. Could you post the answer to your question, as benefit for the community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I used the google cloud connector, which comes pre-installed in the dataproc cluster.

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/install-storage-connector

The steps are precise, but in addition to that, I had to add apt roles in the bucket to my service account.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles

It then worked.

Comment: Can you please specify which exact roles did you add ? I'm facing same issue even when my service account is in `Storage Admin` role.

Comment: I gave the role of storage reader. In addition, make sure that the VM is configured to have access to the Cloud Storage scope.